# Run RSpec with specified ruby interpreter options

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

My RSpec installation works as expected, and I can run it with `./bin/rspec`.
Now I would like to add a ruby interpreter command line option, but I can't find the right location to add this option to the RSpec config.

I am aware of the option to run RSpec from the ruby interpreter by requiring `rspec/autorun`, but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: What command line option are you trying to add? I ask because this would make it clear whether a given answer to your question actually solves the original problem or not. See: [mcve]

Comment: @TomLord Thanks for your response. In my case it is a special Ruby interpreter (TruffleRuby), where I need the options `--jvm` and `--polyglot`.

Comment: Does adding the options to the binstub directly work (and is that a sufficient solution?) I.e. at the top of `./bin/rspec`, change the first line from `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` (or similar) to `#!/usr/bin/env ruby --jvm --polyglot`